# an application to draw rectangle in VC++ MFC creates errors for CDC objects

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I want to draw a rectangle in the dialog, after clicking button. to do this I have written a following code,

```
void CAnalysisofasinglyreinforcedbeamDlg::OnBnClickedCalculate()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
CDC *pdc = NULL;
this->DrawRect(pdc);    
}

void CAnalysisofasinglyreinforcedbeamDlg::DrawRect(CDC* pDC)
{
       // create and select a solid blue brush
       CBrush brushBlue(RGB(0, 0, 255));
       CBrush* pOldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&brushBlue);

     // create and select a thick, black pen
    CPen penBlack;
    penBlack.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&penBlack);

    // get our client rectangle
   CRect rect;
   GetClientRect(rect);

   // shrink our rect 20 pixels in each direction
   rect.DeflateRect(20, 20);

   // draw a thick black rectangle filled with blue
   pDC->Rectangle(rect);

   // put back the old objects
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldBrush);
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen);
}
```

The code while execution gives the following error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x59B7695B (mfc110ud.dll) in beam.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

I am using VS2012 for development

Comment: Well, you are passing in a `NULL` pointer, then call methods through it. What else did you expect?

Comment: :) yea I saw that, happens when a non-regular programmer codes.. :P  thanks for the input though.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a NULL display context. Try doing this instead:

```
void CAnalysisofasinglyreinforcedbeamDlg::OnBnClickedCalculate()
{
    // draw on client dc
    CClientDC pDC(this);
    DrawRect(&pDC);    
}
```

Comment: well, that's a silly and an embarrassing mistake... thanks for bringing it out though! :)